# Pytorch: Automatically determine the input shape of Linear layer after Conv1d

Tags: python, deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I want to build a model with several `Conv1d` layers followed by several `Linear` layers. `Conv1d` layers will work for data of any given length, the problem comes at the first `Linear` layer, because the data length is unknown at initialization time. Every time the length of the input data changes, the output size of `Conv1d` layers will change, hence a change in the required `in_features` of the first `Linear` layer.

Note: I learned CNN and I am aware of how to calculate the output dimensions by hand. I am looking for a programmatic way to determine it, because I have to experiment **many** times with different length of input data.

Question: In **pytorch**, how do you automatically figure out the output dimension after many `Conv1d` layers and set the `in_features` for the following `Linear` layer?

Comment: Relevant other post: [*"How to compute the parameters in the CNN classifier?"*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78092923/how-to-compute-the-parameters-in-the-cnn-classifier/78094267#78094267)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the builtin [`nn.LazyLinear`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.LazyLinear.html) which will find the `in_features` on the first inference and initialize the appropriate number of weights accordingly:

```
linear = nn.LazyLinear(out_features)
```