# How to compute the parameters in the CNN classifier?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I have implemented the CNN model for mnist. I was able understand how to compute the parameters and shapes for different layers of CNN but I wanted to understand how determine the `in_features` and `out_features` in classifier part, specifically the `nn.Linear()`. Also, how to select `in_channels`, `out_channels` in `nn.Conv2d`?

```
class CNNclf(nn.Module):
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.net = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Conv2d(in_channels=1, out_channels=64, kernel_size=3),
        nn.ReLU(),
        nn.MaxPool2d((2, 2), stride=2),
        nn.Conv2d(in_channels=64, out_channels=128, kernel_size=3),
        nn.ReLU(),
        nn.MaxPool2d((2, 2), stride=3),
        nn.Conv2d(in_channels=128, out_channels=64, kernel_size=3),
        nn.ReLU(),
        nn.MaxPool2d((2, 2), stride=2))
    self.clf = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Flatten(),
        nn.Linear(64, 20, bias=True),
        nn.ReLU(),
        nn.Linear(20, 10, bias=True))

def forward(self, x):
    x = self.net(x)
    x = self.clf(x)
    return x
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a typical question when it comes to CNN, there are many posts alike where users encounter the same type of error originating from this.

> RuntimeError: mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (`i`x`j` and `k`x`l`)

I will provide a canonical answer here.

When working with [`nn.Conv2d`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Conv2d.html), intermediate tensors will be four-dimensional: `(b, c, h, w)`. Convolutions work spatially, they move across the tensor across the height and width dimensions (for 2D convs). The number of output channels is determined by the number of filters in the convolution layer which operates independently of each other. You can read more about convolution layers and sizes in: [***Understanding convolutional layers shapes***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65554032/understanding-convolutional-layers-shapes/65612711#65612711).

When it comes to CNN architectures, you have to accommodate for a change in dimensionality when moving from the convolutional part (feature extractor) to the fully connected layers (classifier). In the general case, the tensor shape is going from 4D to 2D. This requires some form of spatiality reduction: either

- via flattening, leading to a shape of `(b, c*h*w)`. This can be done using [`nn.Flatten`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Flatten.html);
- or using a pooling operation such as a maximum [`nn.MaxPool2d`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.MaxPool2d.html) or average pooling [`nn.AdaptiveAvgPool2d`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.AdaptiveAvgPool2d.html), resulting in a reduced shape of `(b, c, h', w')`. If `h'` and `w'` are not singletons, a flattening operation is still necessary.

Ultimately the output shape of the last convolution layer depends on two things: the input shape and the number and sizes of convolutions preceding it.
The above error refers to a shape mismatch between the output of the CNN and the shape expected by the linear layer. `i` is the batch size, `j` is the *actual flattened feature length*, `k` is the `in_features` of the first linear layer, and `l` is its `out_features`. So in case you get this error, you already know which `in_features` to use!

To anticipate this error and avoid throwing it while debugging the architecture, another way to determine `in_features` is by truncating the model (removing all linear layers) and performing inference with dummy data. Observing the output shape of that inference will inform you of the `in_features` to adopt.

```
>>> CNNclf().net(torch.rand(3,1,100,100)).shape # adapt with your input shape
torch.Size([3, 64, 7, 7])
```

Therefore the spatial dimension is `7x7` and the channel count is `64`, so the feature dimension is `64*7*7 = 3136`. In this case, the first linear layer must be initialized as `nn.Linear(3136, 20, bias=True)`.

Since [version 1.8](https://pytorch.org/docs/1.8.0/generated/torch.nn.LazyLinear.html?highlight=lazylinear), there exists a class [`nn.LazyLinear`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.LazyLinear.html) which infers the `in_features` automatically at runtime (during the first inference of the model). In this case, no need to perform the dummy inference yourself, simply use `nn.LazyLinear(20, bias=True)`